# Python- how do I get output written into a single column of a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I've written a script that will calculate the reaction rates of a given atmosphere based on input from files.  That part of the script that works fine- what I'm having trouble with is output.

The output I'm trying to write looks like this:

```
[4.0645563275808397e+40, 2.132787340925467e+34, 1.1095439676449723e+34, 8.8519070848594178e+30, 5.712962894343884e+29, 8.59176710723335e+25, 2.2776609537205616e+27, 1.0754560423907579e+29, 1.207315366535562e+32, 3.704635984045113e+37, 3.6601067774637497e+36, 2.9774080573246763e+41, 1.6013846123116079e+42, 68756936.415690869, 37101276694.104965, 1261680029767.3533,...]
```

There are 560 reaction rates in total.

I've been trying to use csv.writer to write this to csv file- which it can and does do.  The problem is instead of creating one column with 560 rows to store the output, csv.writer keeps producing 560 columns with one row.  How do I get it to write the output in the format that I want? I already tried numpy.transpose, and that didn't have any effect.

Here's the relevant code:

```
rate_list=[]
for i in range (1,560): 
    A_no=int(Ar.iloc[i]) #index number for first reactant
    B_no=int(Br.iloc[i]) #index number for second reactant
    k=mydict['variable']['k'][i][29] #Grabs reaction rate constant
    A_ymix=mydict['variable']['ymix'][29][A_no] #Grabs abundance for first reactant
    B_ymix=mydict['variable']['ymix'][29][B_no] #Grabs abundance for second reactant
    rate=A_ymix*B_ymix*N*k
    rate_list.append(rate)
with open('reaction rate list.csv','w') as output:
     writer= csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(rate_list)
```

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no details for ar, BR, mydict etc, hence I created a moc list of large numbers and then wrote that to a csv file. 
Hope this helps.

Below creates rate list of large/exponential numbers of size 560.

```
import random
rate_list= [str(random.randint(10000000000,999999999999)) for _ in xrange(1,561)]

 >>> rate_list
    ['77041105830', '92494887483', ..........., '749368445154', '435710931425']
```

Then we open output file to write and iterate through index of rate_list to write each element to a new line. This can be adopted for your case.

```
with open('reaction rate list.csv','w') as output:
    for i in range(0,560):
        output.write(rate_list[i])
        output.write('\n')
```

**Result**
This results into output file of single column with 560 lines.

[image]

Comment: If my answer resolves your issue do consider accepting it so that loop is closed.  Pls. see this link on how to accept an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with csv writer, but  if you want it in a single line it wouldn't be to hard to just use a standard file writer

```
rate_list=[]
out='['
for i in range (1,560): 
    A_no=int(Ar.iloc[i]) #index number for first reactant
    B_no=int(Br.iloc[i]) #index number for second reactant
    k=mydict['variable']['k'][i][29] #Grabs reaction rate constant
    A_ymix=mydict['variable']['ymix'][29][A_no] #Grabs abundance for first reactant
    B_ymix=mydict['variable']['ymix'][29][B_no] #Grabs abundance for second reactant
    rate=A_ymix*B_ymix*N*k
    out= out + rate + ','
out = out.replace(out[len(out) - 1], ']')
f = open('list.csv', 'w+')
open.write(out)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make each value a row append a list with a single item instead of the item. Also, open the file with `newline=''` argument.

```
...
    rate_list.append([rate])
with open('reaction rate list.csv','w') as output:
     writer= csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', newline='')
writer.writerows(rate_list)
```